MS Access 2010: How to Run a query on save command
I'm trying to automatically run a number of queries when I save my DB .. although not entirely sure I need to?
Use Case:
I am accessing the query results through a 3rd party application connected via OLEDB. When I make changes to the primary DB data I want to ensure the queries are also up to date so the latest data is picked up by the other application.
Question: Do I have to run the query inside Access to get it to update the results? If so is there any easy way to run all my queries on the save command? I don't know VBA and am not using any forms.

I guess not. But try and you'll see.

A query picks the data when it is executed. If you still see the query result and some other process or person changes the source data, the query result will not be updated. To to do this you have to execute the query again.

The query result is not stored anywhere. The one who executes the query gets the data as Recordset which can be enumerated. So, clearly NO - do not execute the queries when saving or closing the DB!
This also means that a SELECT query always returns the most actual data, and you do not have to worry about refreshing the query somehow when the data has changed.
